# What workaround can I use for compile error C2797 in the following C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 after update 3 and am getting error C2797, "List initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented", see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx. I want to use a workaround in the following C++ code but I just can't figure out or find out what it should be. Could you please give me a suggestion?

This is where I believe I need the workaround

```
class Shape  {  // deals with color and style, and holds sequence of lines
protected:
    Shape{initializer_list<Point> lst};  // add() the Points to this Shape
```

and a Point is

```
#ifndef POINT_GUARD
#define POINT_GUARD

typedef void (*Callback)(void*,void*);

namespace Graph_lib {

struct Point {
    int x,y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }
    Point() :x(0), y(0) { }

    Point& operator+=(Point d) { x+=d.x; y+=d.y; return *this; }
};

inline bool operator==(Point a, Point b) { return a.x==b.x && a.y==b.y; }

inline bool operator!=(Point a, Point b) { return !(a==b); }


}
#endif
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably meant `Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor is defied with parentheses not curly braces.

```
Shape{initializer_list<Point> lst};
```

Becomes

```
Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst);
```

Then you can use curly braces to make an object like:

```
Shape shape{point1, point2, point3 };
```